# Balance equation for trilead tetra oxide -> lead monoxide + oxygen

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Please give me the answer for this question.
I am having difficulty in this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no effort in the question.

Comment: Homework questions like this are often better when you show an effort to solve the problem yourself, and then come to us for any particular issues you are having.

Comment: Your question become victim of downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I won't do your homework for you, but I can show you how to balance equations. Balancing equations is pretty simple once you get the hang of it. First, let's look at an unbalanced equation:

$$\ce{Al2O3 -> Al + O2}$$

The number of atoms for each element on either side of the reaction must match. On the left side there are 2 aluminum atoms and 3 oxygen atoms. On the right side there is 1 aluminum atom and 2 oxygen atoms. Keep in mind that oxygen is one of the diatomic gases that must be bonded to itself when alone as $\ce{O2}$. Now that we have counted the atoms on each side, we can balance them out, by changing the coefficients or number of each molecule in the reaction. There needs to be the same number of atoms on each side, yielding:

$$\ce{Al2O3 -> 2 Al + 1.5 O2}$$

While the number of atoms is now balanced, there is a problem. You can't have a fraction of a molecule in an equation, so we have to double all of the coefficients to change the 1.5 into 3.

$$\ce{2 Al2O3 -> 4 Al + 3 O2}$$

We are finally done. As you can see there are 4 aluminum atoms and 6 oxygen atoms on the right side and the left side. That is how you balance an equation and I hope it helps you solve your equation! Feel free to ask any questions.